# Unpermitted parameters for active_admin Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using Nested form in Active admin resource but value of nested attribute not save in model.

here is detail of my models -

```
class Exceed::Assessment < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :assessment_infos, :class_name => "Exceed::AssessmentInfo", :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :assessment_infos, allow_destroy: true

end
```

next model -

```
class Exceed::AssessmentInfo < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :assessment

end
```

and here is the active admin resource of Exceed::Assessment

```
ActiveAdmin.register Exceed::Assessment do

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Exceed Details" do
      f.input :exceed_id, :label => 'Exceed Type', :as => :select, :collection => Exceed.all.map{|s| ["#{s.exceed_type}", s.id]}
      f.input :exceed_section_id, :label => 'section', :as => :select, :collection => ExceedSection.all.map{|s| ["#{s.section}", s.id]}
      f.input :guideline, label: "Section Guideline"   
    end
    f.has_many :assessment_infos do |q|
      q.input :information
    end
    f.actions
  end

  controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit exceed_assessment: [:exceed_id, :exceed_section_id, :guideline],
      assessment_infos_attributes: [:information]
    end
  end


end
```

from my active admin form I fill details of exceed_assessment and nested form assessment_info.
Exceed_assessment details are successfully save in model but assessment_info not save.
when I check it on console it show error message -

```
Unpermitted parameters: assessment_infos_attributes
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, commit
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some silly mistakes, after correct them its working.

Firstly, in my **Assessment_info** model there is a column 'exceed_assessment_id'. I change it to 'assessment_id' because my model is belongs_to Assessment model.

Second I slightly change syntax of Permit params, like this -

```
controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit exceed_assessment: [:id, :exceed_id, :exceed_section_id, :guideline,
      assessment_infos_attributes: [:assessment_id, :information],]
    end
  end
```